# Cannot query 'PublisherQuerySet' attributes in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am currently building a website in DjangoCMS and I want to query the Title model from cms and compare it against request.path. From there I will load a prefiltered version of the assets. Everything works up until I compare `page_obj.title`. I return the error `'PublisherQuerySet' object has no attribute 'title'` but I have checked the model and it does have a title attribute. Is there a certain way I need to query that `PublisherQuerySet` object as opposed to a regular `QuerySet` so that it pulls it back?

in the `obj.name` object directly before it worked just fine. Feels like I am missing something obvious.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
import os
from cms.models import Title

def AssetListView(request, *args, **kwargs):
    path = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(request.path))
    print(path)

    page_obj = Title.objects.filter(slug=path)[:1]
    print (page_obj)

    for obj in Tag.objects.all():
        print (obj.name)
        if obj.name == page_obj.title:
            return HttpResponse('<h1>test HTML<h1>')
```

Comment: Note that `page_obj` is *not* a `Title` object, but a `QuerySet` of `Title` objects.

Comment: yes, with `Title.objects.filter(..).first()` it will return the *first* item (or `None` if no such element exists). But I think it might be worth investigating why there are duplicate slugs, normally a slug should be *unique*.

Comment: There are multiple slugs for the pages that are `is_draft=True` and `is_draft=False`. I thought it was weird at first too but I think DjangoCMS handles all that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write:

```
page_obj = Title.objects.filter(slug=path)[:1]
```

this means that `page_obj` is **not** a `Title` object, but a `QuerySet` that will contain zero or more (here at most one) `Title` element. Just like a `list` of `int`egers is not an `int`eger itself.

You probably want to use `.first()` here, which will return a `Title` object, or `None` in case no such element exists, like:

```
def AssetListView(request, *args, **kwargs):
    path = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(request.path))
    print(path)

    page_obj = Title.objects.filter(slug=path).first()
    print (page_obj)

    for obj in Tag.objects.all():
        print (obj.name)
        if obj.name == page_obj.title:
            return HttpResponse('test HTML')
```

Note that here you might want to return something in case no `obj.name == page_obj.title` holds.

A slug is however frequently a *unique* attribute. So normally a `.get(..)` instead of a `.filter(..).first()` is a more preferrable way, since then we at least know when something is wrong. It thus might be worth investigating why multiple records have the same slug.